# Trying to Store GTIN numbers in WordPress Database via WooCommerce CSV Import

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, metadata, import-from-csv

**Trying to Store GTIN numbers in WordPress Database via WooCommerce CSV Import**

In Excel I created my CSV in which there is a column called **meta:wpseo_global_identifier_values**

Through excel formulas I have created the value below with the dummy GTIN 1111111111111 to match how it is stored in the database table **_postmeta**

a:6:{s:5:"gtin8";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin12";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin13";s:9:"1111111111111";s:6:"gtin14";s:0:"";s:4:"isbn";s:0:"";s:3:"mpn";s:0:"";}

Then from the excel file, I generate the CSV file.

However after I import the CSV file and check the database I find that the data is input as below (with the extra characters **s:134:"** in the beginning and **";** the end) and as a result, the GTIN is not visible on the website backend.

s:134:"a:6:{s:5:"gtin8";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin12";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin13";s:9:"1111111111111";s:6:"gtin14";s:0:"";s:4:"isbn";s:0:"";s:3:"mpn";s:0:"";}";

When I manually remove the extra characters the value is successfully stored and visible on the website backend.

I have tried to understand why this is happening but to no avail, does anyone have any idea why this might be so?

Thanks

Comment: Give this a try - https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

Comment: Thanks but the plugin gave an error when it got to import the meta:wpseo_global_identifier_values

Comment: The problem is you're trying to create a serialized string and the values are incorrect. For example, in this part here: s:9:"1111111111111", I'm going to explain what this all means:
- s: string
- 9: length
- "1111111111111": value
So, you can see that the length is not correct. It should be 13, making that part of the serialized string look something like:
s:13:"1111111111111"

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Thanks to a good friend we found a temporary hack that works around the issue until the team at Yoast develop a more straightforward way of importing these global identifiers through the native woocomemrce importer.

Basically after each CSV import run this SQL query.

UPDATE _postmeta
SET meta_value = TRIM("\";" FROM substring(meta_value, locate("{", meta_value) -4, length(meta_value) -4))
WHERE meta_key = 'wpseo_global_identifier_values'
and SUBSTRING(meta_value, 1, 7) = 's:134:"'

Changes this:

s:134:"a:6:{s:5:"gtin8";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin12";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin13";s:13:"1111111111111";s:6:"gtin14";s:0:"";s:4:"isbn";s:0:"";s:3:"mpan";s:0:"";}";

to this:

a:6:{s:5:"gtin8";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin12";s:0:"";s:6:"gtin13";s:13:"1111111111111";s:6:"gtin14";s:0:"";s:4:"isbn";s:0:"";s:3:"mpan";s:0:"";}

And GTIN value is added to the products.